# How to add a "Loading..." image to show that vis.js timeline is still getting data and rendering it

Tags: javascript, jquery, vis.js

I am using vis.js to display a schedules timeline by making somewhat around 60-70 REST calls that are kicked off in parallel. The timeline gets the data from the rest callback and populates in its view. However sometimes its hard to tell if the timeline is still waiting for more data to be loaded or if its already done.

Is there a way I can show a "Loading..." gif/image while the timeline is actively loading new items into its view?

I have already tried `$.document(ready)` and it does not seem to work with parallel ajax calls.

Comment: " 60-70 REST calls" is a bit of a problem. Why does it take so many calls to build up your page?

Comment: It's how the backend is designed which I have no control over. I need to make one call to get a list of people and a separate call for each person in that people's list to get more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the Timeline itself, it's about fetching data asynchronously.

Basically you have to:

- Display an loading image on screen
- Keep count of how many ajax requests have been started
- When the response of an ajax request comes in, reduce the counter by one (also when a call failed!)
- As soon as the counter becomes zero, all requests are finished. Then hide the loading image
- If any of the requests failed, show an error message on screen